# Mysqli: __construct() returns NULL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I have a DB set up and I'm using a class to connect to it that extends Mysqli. Here are the relevant lines of code:

```
class Db extends Mysqli {
  public $result = Array();

  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DB);
  }
```

I've checked the connection info, and it works fine with the `mysql_connect()` function.

My PHP version is 5.3, and I'm using MAMP 1.9.5 to run the environment.

So on to the issue I'm having - if I `var_dump()` the connection, it returns as NULL. Not false, but null. Now I've checked the specs and, just like it's predecessor `mysql_connect()`, it is supposed to return false in case of the connection failing. So what possible circumstance would return false?

Comment: "I've checked the specs and, just like it's predecessor mysql_connect(), it is supposed to return false in case of the connection failing" Really?  [The docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect.php) say "OO syntax only: If a connection fails an object is still returned. To check if the connection failed then use either the mysqli_connect_error() function or the mysqli->connect_error property as in the preceding examples."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not showing the complete code. This is what you have done:

```
class Db extends Mysqli {
    function __construct() {
       $r =  parent::__construct(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DB);
       var_dump($r);
    }
}
```

And naturally this returns `NULL`. The parent constructor never returns anything. Constructers are not supposed to return anything. They fill up the freshly created object instance.

You will find the connection handle and other properties in the returned object, **after** your constructor is done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's because of your capitalization.  Extending the nonexistent class `Mysqli` works, and its nonexistent method `connect()` seems to return `NULL`

```
class Db extends Mysqli
```

Should be

```
class Db extends mysqli
```

Comment: Nope. PHP language constructs and raw identifiers are case-insensitive. (Unless you use a borked framework whose autoloader does not understand the language semantics.)

Answer (score 0):

@Michael is likely right about the spelling issue, but there's another issue here:

Why are you not using [`PDO`](http://php.net/pdo)?  `PDO` is installed by default on PHP 5.1 and newer.

`PDO` abstracts the database layer so you can write code against any database that supports PDO without having to make majorchanges.